# Array element not splicing into separate array - FreeCodeCamp > Chunky Monkey

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm working through the FreeCodeCamp challenges and I'm stuck on the following one:

> Our goal for this Algorithm is to split arr (first argument) into
>   smaller chunks of arrays with the length provided by size (second
>   argument). There are several green checks (objectives) our code needs
>   to pass in order to complete this Algorithm:
>
> (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2) is expected to return [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
>
> ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3) is expected to return [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
>
> ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2) is expected to return [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
>
> ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4) is expected to return [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
>
> ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2) is expected to return [[0, 1], [2, 3],
>   [4, 5], [6, 7], [8]].

Here is the code I've come up with:

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {

  var newArray = [];
  var holdArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i += size) {
    holdArray = arr.slice(0, size);
    removed = arr.splice(0, size);
    newArray.push(holdArray);
  }
  if (arr.length !== 0) {
    newArray.push(arr);
    return newArray;
  }
  else return newArray; 
}

chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2);
```

The algorithm works for all of the objectives, except for the last one. Instead of returning:

[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8]]

it's returning:

[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8]] - and I can't work out why.

Any help shedding some light on where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't blame you for being confused, it took me a while to find the problem, too.

It started with identifying that your `for` loop was a bit odd - you weren't using the `i` variable for anything. Additionally, you were `splice()`-ing the original array down each iteration, so your intention was correct - to wait until there is less than `size` elements left in the array.

So I expressed that as a `while` loop instead, and voila, it works:

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {

  var newArray = [];
  var holdArray = [];
  while (arr.length >= size) {
    holdArray = arr.slice(0, size);
    removed = arr.splice(0, size);
    newArray.push(holdArray);
  }
  if (arr.length !== 0) {
    newArray.push(arr);
    return newArray;
  }
  else return newArray; 
}

chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2);
```

Comment: Ah ok, I see where I've gone wrong. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You are recaluculating length again and again, but you forgot that you are actually removing elements from arr, so length would not be the same as size increases length decreases,either you can give as while loop or keep original length in a variable and check

function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {

```
  var newArray = [];
  var holdArray = [];
  var length=arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i <=length; i += size) {
    holdArray = arr.slice(0, size);
    removed = arr.splice(0, size);
    newArray.push(holdArray);
  }
  if (arr.length !== 0) {
    newArray.push(arr);
    return newArray;
  }
  else return newArray; 
}

chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. This solution works for the argument I was getting stuck on, but now it doesn't work for the following arguments:

(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2) is expected to return [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3) is expected to return [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]

([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2) is expected to return [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]